# Convert logical to char (still binary) class

Tags: matlab

I have this structure

```
Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes
txt        8x7            56     logical 

8×7 logical array
0   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   1   0
0   0   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   1   0   1
```

that I want to convert into that one

```
Name         Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
txt_bin      8x7             112    char

1010110
1100101
1110010
1101110
1100001
1101101
0101110
0001010
```

Both are the same "size". I want the second structure so I will be able to get the text through `char(bin2dec(txt))`

Is there a well-known function? I tried unsuccessfully with some `reshape`..

To clarify the context, I have a clear text that I convert to binary, so I can make a XOR with a passphrase (Vernam crypto), and now I want to transcript this new binary result into char to be able to send the encrypted message.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt = logical([...
0   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   1   0
0   0   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   1   0   1]);
ch = '01';

txt_bin = ch([~txt(1:3,:);txt(4:7,:);~txt(8,:)] + 1)
```

or

```
char([~txt(1:3,:);txt(4:7,:);~txt(8,:)]+'0')
```

Comment: Just think that `txt_bin = ch(~txt + 1)` should be`txt_bin = ch(txt + 1)`

Comment: @obchardon OK, answer updated some rows are different!

Comment: I dont know if it's in the spirit but seeing your `+'0'` gave me **the** hint. 
So just using `char(txt + '0')` worked perfectly !

Can you explain me the difference between `txt` and `~txt`?

Comment: @ before I edited the answer I wrote the code like you. but I saw that some of rows of your input and output are different. for example last row of `txt` is `[1   1   1   0   1   0   1]` but last row of `txt_bin` is `0001010` so I applied not operator `~`

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. Ok now I understand perfectly. It's my fault, the two matrix should be different by their content, not by their size. Output is a xor between Input and an encryption key. So thanks a lot, it's working perfectly and I learned new things!